# Network In greater than Network Out?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tcp

Stat Image: http://carzz.co/network.png

Running a small image website on EC2 without much traffic to speak of (800 user sessions per day). In looking at the EC2 Monitoring on the newly created instance, I see that Network In is significantly higher than Network Out for the instance. I should note that the DB server is external. So I assume the Network In data consists of visitor browser information/requests and the DB data (tiny recordsets). Outgoing data is obviously DB queries, HTTP content, site files, and image content. So, how could the incoming data be greater than the outgoing data?

My only thought would be a DDOS kind of scenario. Perhaps I got terribly unlucky and assigned an Elastic IP that has been targeted.

Comment: can't answer your question. but I would check what kind of connections you mostly have, for example look at the outputs of `netstat -nta` and `netstat -nua`. if you still can't find the reason you might want to look at the `ntop` utility.

Comment: There are a variety of possibilities. People uploading huge images that exceed your limit would do it - lots of network in as they upload, but as you'd reject the file it'd never be displayed out to any user.

Comment: You may also want to try the iptraf utility.  Those charts are not very clear in terms of Megabits/sec.  Using ipraf/ntop or something similar will allow you to see inbound/outbound bandwidth in real time.   Also the netstat results are useful in identifying the port.  I have seen cases where recycled IP addresses have a lot of traffic due to incorrect DNS pointing an old domain to your newly acquired IP.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your inbound traffic in is a heartbeat check from AWS management.

*Edit:*

I've done some looking, and I've found that AWS sends metadata to the instance.
In powershell (v3) you can use `Invoke-WebRequest http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` to examine it. I'm guessing that some of this data is gotten by requests from a service running on the instance to AWS.

Comment: Ok, but am I reading it correctly that it is 50MB? 50Kb is completely understandable, but not into the MB range I would not think. Esp since Network Out is service images about 75kb each.

Comment: You're reading that correctly. I've noticed the same thing on my EC2 instances. Since inbound isn't metered, and there haven't been any reliability/uptime issues, I haven't worried about it much.

Answer (score 0):

Any server using default ports(22, 25, 80, 443, ...) will be scanned by a huge number or crawler/bots scanning for vulnerabilities or just indexing the internet. That can build up into a lot of incoming data.

You may want to try and install `fail2ban` or any other IDS to reduce that flow.

On the other hand, 50kBps isn't that much if your hosting company provide servers with 100Mbps andunlimited Traffic.

Comment: Also known as Internet Background Noise: [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise)

Comment: I will look at fail2ban, but the amount appears to be 50MB, not Kb, or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: I assumed since there's a plot every 10 minutes, that was an average or 30MB/10min which is 50kBps. But if that's just bytes per scecond probes every 10min, that's 50MBps and that's not just noise.