# Why is my EC2 network in around double my network out?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2AmH.jpg

I administer a web server cluster within AWS for a client, and am wondering why my instances' Network In is consistently about double what Network Out is.

There is a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/564649/network-in-greater-than-network-out/564658), but the answers are unsatisfactory; AWS heartbeating would not mirror traffic shape, neither would internet background noise, and my users aren't regularly making large requests.

I personally would expect the numbers to be at least reversed; HTTP requests are small, and the rendered HTML is not.

What is going on?  How can I better investigate?

UPDATES:  My application is WordPress.  It is fetching data from the database and memcache, (RDS and ElastiCache), in response to requests.

My web server is not being attacked.  The access logs correspond exactly with real requests.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a case of needing to properly get to know your application. What is it actually doing, what data is it fetching and from where?

Comment: Is your web server being attacked in any way? Check the log for GET and POST. Is anything hitting the IP but being rejected because it doesn't match your domains? After that consider setting up [VPC Flow Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html).

Comment: I have updated my question.